# python append two zipped lists into docx file

Tags: python, for-loop, zip, docx, f-string

```
john = [...]
jake = [...]       

for a,b in zip(john, jake):
    document = Document()
    document.add_paragraph(f"{a}---------------{b} \n")
    document.save("docxpy.docx")
```

I have two lists and want to append their values as "a----------------b" into "docxpy.docx" file. But every single time it appends only one of them. I am new to python please font make fun of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
john = [...]
jake = [...]       

document = Document() # this needs to be before the for loop

for a,b in zip(john, jake):
    document.add_paragraph(f"{a}---------------{b} \n")

document.save("docxpy.docx") # this should come after the for loop
```

The problem is you initialized `document` inside the loop, which means every iteration it's reinitializing `document` with an empty `Document()` object. As a result, at the last iteration of your loop, you end up with a document that only contains the very last pair of `a,b`, which is why you see only one line in your output document. Initializing the `document` variable before the for loop should do the trick.

In addition, you should put the `save` method call after the loop. This isn't strictly necessary (you'll notice you get the same result either way), but it saves time/resources since you need only write the file to disk once at the very end once all the paragraphs have been added.